# OPENCART PayPal Payments Pro (UK) Orders appear as cancelled

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

i'm using a default installation of OPENCART and am using the PayPal Payments Pro (UK) Module to take payments, as well as using the PAYPAL EXPRESS CHECKOUT, all is fine with the express checkout but with PayPal Payments Pro, the order is automatically set to cancelled, and then pending straight away. And it notify the customer that the order is cancelled, but its not...

Here is a screenshot of the PAYPAL Module settings [image]

Which are all fine, but this is how an order a customer places is appearing.

[image]

Why would this happen when, within the paypal module its set to "PENDING" as the order status, why is the customer getting notified that the order was cancelled when it isnt....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because in Your store settings, tab *Options*, section *Checkout*, You have set the setting **Order Status** to *Cancelled*.

When using PP Pro UK, after the payment is being successfully processed, the *blank* order is confirmed with the status **Order Status** (config key `config_order_status_id`) thus set to *Cancelled* in Your case. Afterwards it is set to the status defined in PP Pro UK settings, thus *Pending* (config key `pp_pro_uk_order_status_id`).

To fix this, go to Your administration -> System -> Settings -> go edit Your store -> navigate to tab *Options* -> scroll down to section *Checkout* and at config item *Order Status* set the status to **Pending**.

This should fix Your issue.

Comment: PERFECT! thanks lol, i missed this as i have multistore setup with 90 stores on one installation :)